# i got 2 toolbar when multi select in listview

Tags: java, android, listview, android-studio, toolbar

Hi everyone I got a problem with my app SMS, when I long press on a contact it show the new toolbar but I don't know who to remove the other toolbar :/

[image]

if you can help me thank you ..

Here is my Main activity :

```
package com.ducha.messavtext;

import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.content.ContentUris;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.BaseColumns;
import android.provider.ContactsContract;
import android.provider.Telephony;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.Log;
import android.util.SparseBooleanArray;
import android.view.ActionMode;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AbsListView;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;

import com.ducha.training3.R;

import java.util.ArrayList;

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements BaseColumns {

    private Cursor cursor;
    private Cursor cursorPhone;
    private Cursor cursorContact;

    private final Uri uriSms      = Telephony.Sms.CONTENT_URI;
    private final Uri uriPhone    = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI;
    private final Uri uri         = Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox");


    private String body;
    private String numero;
    private String id;
    private String contact;

    private final String[] selectionSms         = new String[]{Telephony.Sms._ID, Telephony.Sms.BODY, Telephony.Sms.THREAD_ID, Telephony.Sms.ADDRESS, Telephony.Sms.DATE, Telephony.Sms.READ,};
    private final String[] selectionPhone       = new String[]{ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER,};
    private final String[] selectionContact     = new String[]{ContactsContract.Contacts._ID, ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME,};

    public static ArrayList<CreateContactAdapter>   listContact = new ArrayList<>();;
    public static boolean                           runMain;
    public static ContactAdapter                    adapter;
    public static byte[]                            myPhoto;

    private         ArrayList<String>   idList          = new ArrayList<>();;
    private         Context             ctx             = this;
    private         int                 read;
    private         int                 messageUnread   = 0;
    private         ListView            lv;
    private         ArrayList<String>   diffNumber;
    private         byte[]              photo;
    private         Toolbar             toolbar;

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        runMain = true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        clearIfNotEmpty();
        isTheDefaultApp();
        findId();
        getInfoMain();
        getMyContactPicture();
        ConfigToolbar();
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
        lv.setChoiceMode(AbsListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL);

        lv.setMultiChoiceModeListener(new AbsListView.MultiChoiceModeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemCheckedStateChanged(ActionMode mode, int position, long id, boolean checked) {
                final int selectedItem = lv.getCheckedItemCount();
                mode.setTitle(selectedItem + " Item selected");
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {

                mode.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.select_menu, menu);
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode arg0, MenuItem item) {
                switch (item.getItemId()) {
                    case R.id.remove_item:
                        SparseBooleanArray select = adapter.getSelectedIds();

                        for (int i = (select.size() - 1); i >= 0; i--) {
                            if (select.valueAt(i)) {
                                CreateContactAdapter contact = (CreateContactAdapter) adapter.getItem(select.keyAt(i));
                                adapter.remove(contact);
                            }
                        }
                        arg0.finish();
                        return true;

                    default:
                        return false;
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {
                adapter.removeSelection();
            }
        });
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Intent intent   = new Intent(MainActivity.this, PrintMessage.class);
                String persoId  = listContact.get(position).id;
                String numero   = listContact.get(position).numero;
                String contact  = listContact.get(position).contact;
                String body     = listContact.get(position).body;
                byte[] bmp      = listContact.get(position).photo;
                intent.putExtra("id", persoId);
                intent.putExtra("numero", numero);
                intent.putExtra("contact", contact);
                intent.putExtra("photo", bmp);
                markMessageRead(ctx, numero, body);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }

    private void clearIfNotEmpty() {
        if (!listContact.isEmpty())
            listContact.clear();
    }

    private void getMyContactPicture() {
        Uri uriContact  = Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI, Uri.encode("0659641613"));
        cursorContact   = this.getContentResolver().query(uriContact, selectionContact, null, null, null);
        cursorContact.moveToFirst();
        long idContact = cursorContact.getLong(0);
        myPhoto = openPhoto(idContact);
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
    private void isTheDefaultApp() {
        final String packageName = MainActivity.this.getPackageName();
        if (!Telephony.Sms.getDefaultSmsPackage(MainActivity.this).equals(packageName)) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Telephony.Sms.Intents.ACTION_CHANGE_DEFAULT);
            intent.putExtra(Telephony.Sms.Intents.EXTRA_PACKAGE_NAME, packageName);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }

    private void findId() {
        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.my_toolbar);
        lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListView01);
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
    public void getInfoMain() {
        cursor = this.getContentResolver().query(uriSms, selectionSms, null, null, "date DESC");
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
                id = cursor.getString(2);
                if (!(idList.contains(id))) {
                    body    = cursor.getString(1);
                    numero  = cursor.getString(3);
                    read    = cursor.getInt(5);
                    if (read == 0)
                        messageUnread++;
                    diffNumber = getDifferentNumber(numero);
                    cursorPhone = this.getContentResolver().query(uriPhone, selectionPhone,
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER + "='" + diffNumber.get(0) +"' OR " +
                                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER + "='" + diffNumber.get(1) + "' OR " +
                                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER + "='" + diffNumber.get(2) + "' OR " +
                                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER + "='" + diffNumber.get(3) + "'", null, null);
                    if (cursorPhone.moveToFirst()) {
                        contact         = cursorPhone.getString(0);
                        Uri uriContact  = Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI, Uri.encode(numero));
                        cursorContact   = this.getContentResolver().query(uriContact, selectionContact, null, null, null);
                        cursorContact.moveToFirst();
                        long idContact = cursorContact.getLong(0);
                        photo = openPhoto(idContact);
                        if (photo != null)
                            listContact.add(new CreateContactAdapter(contact, numero, body, id, photo, read));
                        else
                            listContact.add(new CreateContactAdapter(contact, numero, body, id, null, read));
                    } else {

                        listContact.add(new CreateContactAdapter("no", numero, body, id, null, read));
                    }
                    idList.add(id);
                }
                cursor.moveToNext();
            }
        }
        cursor.close();
        adapter = new ContactAdapter(listContact, this);
    }

    private void ConfigToolbar() {
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        if (messageUnread > 0)
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Messages (" + messageUnread + ")");
        else
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Messages");
    }

    public byte[] openPhoto(long contactId) {
        Uri contactUri  = ContentUris.withAppendedId(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, contactId);
        Uri photoUri    = Uri.withAppendedPath(contactUri, ContactsContract.Contacts.Photo.CONTENT_DIRECTORY);
        Cursor cursor   = getContentResolver().query(photoUri, new String[]{ContactsContract.Contacts.Photo.PHOTO}, null, null, null);
        if (cursor == null) {
            return null;
        }
        try {
            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                byte[] data = cursor.getBlob(0);
                if (data != null) {
                    return data;
                }
            }
        } finally {
            cursor.close();
        }
        return null;
    }

    private void markMessageRead(Context context, String number, String body) {

        Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null);
        try {

            while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                if ((cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("address")).equals(number)) && (cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("read")) == 0)) {
                    if (cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("body")).startsWith(body)) {
                        String SmsMessageId = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("_id"));
                        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                        values.put("read", true);
                        context.getContentResolver().update(Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox"), values, "_id=" + SmsMessageId, null);
                        return;
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Mark Read", "Error in Read: " + e.toString());
        }
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getDifferentNumber(String number) {
        ArrayList<String> num = new ArrayList<>();
        if (number.matches("^[06|07]{2}[0-9]{8}")) {
            num.add(number.replaceAll(".{2}", "$0 "));
            num.add(number.replaceAll("06", "+336"));
            num.add(number.replaceAll(".{2}", "$0 ").replaceAll("0", "+33 "));
            num.add(number);
        } else if (number.matches("[06|07]{2}( [0-9]{2}){4}")) {
            num.add(number.replaceAll(" ", ""));
            num.add(number.replaceAll("0", "+33 "));
            num.add(number.replaceAll(" ", "").replaceAll("0", "+33"));
            num.add(number);
        } else if (number.matches("\\+[3]{2}[0-9]{8}.")) {
            num.add(number.replaceAll("\\+33", "0"));
            num.add(number.replaceAll("\\+33", "0").replaceAll(".{2}", "$0 "));
            num.add(number.replaceAll("\\+33", "0").replaceAll(".{2}", "$0 ").replaceAll("^0", "+33 "));
            num.add(number);
        } else if (number.matches("\\+33 [6|7]( [0-9]{2}){4}")) {
            num.add(number.replaceAll(" ", ""));
            num.add(number.replaceAll(" ", "").replaceAll("\\+33", "0"));
            num.add(number.replaceAll(" ", "").replaceAll("\\+33", "0").replaceAll(".{2}", "$0 "));
            num.add(number);
        } else {
            num.add(numero);
            num.add(numero);
            num.add(numero);
            num.add(numero);
        }
        return num;
    }

    public boolean edit(MenuItem item) {
        // actions
        return true;
    }

    public boolean newMessage(MenuItem item) {
        startActivity(new Intent(this, NewMessage.class));
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()){
                case R.id.setting :
                    startActivity(new Intent(this, Apparence.class));
            }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        runMain = false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding the following to your styles.xml:

```
<style name="MyAppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">

    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/my_primary_color</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/my_primary_dark_color</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/my_accent_color</item>
    <item name="windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>

</style>
```

Comment: i added it in my menu `<item android:name="android:windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>` you miss "andrdoid" in your answer but it doesn't work

Comment: i mean my menu.xml. i added it to my style.xml this time and it doesn't work too

Comment: well .. i got a style for my "custom_toolbar" in style.xml and in my toolbar in "activity_main.xml" i added `android:theme="@style/custom_main"` then i added your line and it doesn't works, then i added your line in "AppTheme" (the default style) and delete the line `android:theme="@style/custom_main"` and it works ! but i don't know why :/ can you explain me ? do you want my style.xml ?